# Wso2 ESB admin services to get available proxies C#

Tags: c#, proxy, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Hello can anyone with some experience using admin services, make me an example of how to consume wso2 ESB's admin services?

If possible I'd like a C# sample. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/proxy-admin/org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ui/4.0.1/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/proxyadmin/ui/client/ProxyServiceAdminClient.java) you can find one such example in Java. You may need to convert the same logic to C#. For Registry a .net client is available as sample [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/.NET+WS-API+Sample) which uses admin service to do Registry operations.

Comment: could you make an example only for adding the proxy with the relative libraries? This code you linked is massive...

Comment: Also I don't understand how it is composed the format ProxyData. I have a proxy in XML as a one-line string, can I pass it in some way?

Comment: [here] (https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/proxy-admin/) you have the complete module which is used in WSO2 ESB to create using UI. I am afraid that there is a small sample for your requirement. What you need to do is Fill proxyData attributes with your proxy's data and pass it to addProxy method. ProxyData class is used to generate the proxy's OMelement and then add to system.

Comment: I am doing it with java now, can you kindly have a look at my other question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402873/wso2-esb-admin-services-to-get-create-proxies-java

Comment: Please Shelan help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583097/wso2-esb-unsupported-media-type