# Wso2 ESB admin services to get Create proxies Java

Tags: java, xml, proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

**1)** Hello I am trying to use the admin services to create an Proxy inside the ESB.

So I have exposed the admin services (Hidden=false)

I have imported the WSDl in my Java project `https://localhost:8243/services/ProxyServiceAdmin?wsdl`

But I cannot workout how to call the method `addProxy` am I using the wrong admin service? Please help with an example of consuming this method.

```
ProxyServiceAdmin ps = new ProxyServiceAdmin();
ps.addProxy(); //wrong
```

**2)** I have a proxy defined as a one-line String, like

```
String xmlproxy="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><proxy xmlns='http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse' name='MyProxy1' transports='https' startOnLoad='true' trace='disable'> <target inSequence='sequence1'>...."
```

Is it possible to add this Proxy by calling some method of the admin services?

thanks a lot for your attention!

**EDIT** I had a look at the WSDL "ProxyServiceAdmin?wsdl"
it says `<wsdl:operation name="addProxy"><http:operation location="addProxy"/><wsdl:input><mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output><mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters"/></wsdl:output>`

so it is there, but why I cannot call it? Why my code does not work as a normal Web Service would? Really, please help. I don't get what i am doing wrong...

```
ProxyServiceAdmin ps = new ProxyServiceAdmin();
ps.addProxy(); //not recognized as an operation of ProxyServiceAdmin even if it is in the wsdl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to use "org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub.ProxyServiceAdminStub" to ad proxy by admin services

Please have a look at following code and comments inline.

```
    String endPoint = *<your backend service url>* +"ProxyServiceAdmin";
    proxyServiceAdminStub = new ProxyServiceAdminStub(endPoint);
```

You have to authenticate your service stub before make any use of it

```
    CarbonUtils.setBasicAccessSecurityHeaders(userName, password,                      
                              proxyServiceAdminStub._getServiceClient());
```

Need to generate ProxyData object of your proxy as synaps xml

```
    String[] transport = {"http", "https"};
    ProxyData data = new ProxyData();
    data.setName(proxyName);
    data.setWsdlURI(*<url to your WSDL>*);
    data.setTransports(transport);
    data.setStartOnLoad(true);       
    data.setEndpointXML("<endpoint xmlns=\"http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse\"><address uri=\"" + serviceEndPoint + "\" /></endpoint>");
    data.setEnableSecurity(true);
    proxyServiceAdminStub.addProxy(data);
```

Thank You,
Dharshana

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good answer, unlucky I have no experience adding external packages, could you briefly explain me how to add "org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub.ProxyServiceAdminStub" do I need a pom file or something similar? thank you a lot!

Comment: If trie to build wso2 code base these dependencies will be resolved.Building up to service stubs will be enough.        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.stub</artifactId>
            <version>${stub.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: And use <repository>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository> as repository

Answer (score 1):

please find the sample to create a proxy using admin service [here](http://blog.shelan.org/2012/09/create-proxy-in-wso2-esb-using-admin.html). I added Darshana's code to a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [JSP page](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/proxy-admin/org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ui/4.0.1/src/main/resources/web/proxyservices/template_pass-through.jsp) is used for creating a pass through proxy. You can fill your proxy data similar to that. if you browse the other jsps you can find similar logics used for different proxy templates. [Here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/proxy-admin) you can find the complete module, both UI and Service code.

Comment: import org.wso2.carbon.proxyadmin.ui.client.ProxyServiceAdminClient; gives error; package does not exists -> how do I get the package? any link to download what I need?

Comment: I though just adding the wsdl to my project was enough

Comment: (http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/carbon/) here you can find the released artifacts.Try adding artifacts named under proxy-admin*  As i mentioned this is not a standalone sample. But the code that is used in product to consume admin service and create proxy service. Adding only the wsdl will not work.